# Why does 7 not exist in Jawa arithmetic?

Tags: star-wars

According to [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jawaese), in Jawaese, the native language of the Jawa species from Tatooine, the number 7 simply doesn't exist.

Counting in Jawaese:

> 1 Po
>   2 Ko
>   3 Kyo
>   4 Yo
>   5 Dyo
>   6 Lyo
>   7 Does not exist in Jawa arithmetic
>   8 Ho
>   9 To
>   10 Kisewa
>   100 Gakisewa
>   1000 Hakisewa
>   100,000,000 Jo jo muma

Does anyone know the secret that lies behind this?

Comment: The Jawas fear number seven, because 7 8 9.

Comment: How reliable is this information? Is [this page](http://www.completewermosguide.com/jawaese.html) the source?

Comment: @coleopterist I took all info from wookipedia, the biggest wiki resource about Star Wars. Well, it's wiki so it cannot be 100% reliable.

Comment: @igor milla: nothing is 100% reliable. The reliability of a wiki is in its references, and looking at those, the information is almost certainly from this book: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Galactic_Phrase_Book_and_Travel_Guide - so that's where to look for details (if there are any, which I doubt).

Comment: If they had six fingers it could be becasue they count in base six - but they don't... Makes no sense

Comment: I give up for now. Every place discussing the issue just copied Wiki info; Burtt himself doesn't seem to have any clear means of contacting him, and this logic probably originated with him as the author of the book @Michael mentioned. Great question!!!

Comment: I still can't get past the fact that *Jo jo muma's so big...*

Comment: What's the canon-rating on that book - do we know if it's a valid source at all?

Comment: Ignoring the 'source' issue for the moment, it made me think of Star Trek: This may be apocryphal, but I believe I remember the Marc Okrand saying that he originally designed Klingon not to have a verb for 'To Be' simply because all terrestrial languages do;  He was just trying to make it different/unique. (The later quoting of Hamlet by a Klingon forced him to rework things.)  I wonder if the 'reasoning' here isn't particularly thought out, but simply a similar attempt to make it inexplicably different.  Short of 'Word-of-God' no real way to know, I suppose.. But it seemed likely.

Comment: @KHW I had the similar thoughts in my mind. It just makes language stand out from all others.

Comment: Not to forget this is extremely impractical. Surely anacient greeks did not include 0 in their number system, nor did they accept negative numbers and irrational numbers. But they did have sane concept of 'numbers' even if their lower bound stopped at 1. If the Jawas have no word for seven, while defining 6 and 8 correctly then they can say goodbye to addition, subtraction, multiplication and division. As Jawas seems to be traders, this makes no sense whatsoever. Not having a word for 7 is not just a language that 'stands out', it's devestating to their entire culture.

Comment: I love the fact that we have a place where we can actually discuss the merits of whether or not "7" exists in the Jawa counting system. That's so awesome!

Comment: Maybe it's bad luck for things to be 7, noting that many hotels don't have a 13th floor for precisely that reason

Comment: I would guess that the social taboo of "seven", assuming there is one, would require a speaker to render it as a math statement
Q: You have six rocks and I give you one more. how many do you have?
A: Five and Two. Or Eight less one. or...

Answer (score 6):

There's no real indication that a count that we would represent as '7' doesn't exist in 'Jawa' arithmetic.

The quoted Wookieepedia article is using [this](http://www.completewermosguide.com/jawaese.html) as a source.

That source is not reasonably sourcing any indication of the numbering, or the reason of the lack of '7'.

Comment: according the [wookipedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ben_Burtt) article about the author of that book: "He has created many of the languages heard in Star Wars—most of which are marked by shared etymological roots with English—and has written the Galactic Phrase Book and Travel Guide". And if this is true, than that book is pretty canonical.

Comment: who's 'he' and which book?

Comment: sorry, it's from the comments under the question. The book — [Galactic Phrase Book & Travel Guide] (Galactic Phrase Book & Travel Guide). This book mentioned as a resource for the article about Jawa language. And "he" is an author of that book. But, yes, there is no prove that the info originally from him, and his book